# Is Possible to send GeoZones based pushes with Pushwoosh Remote API + Phonegap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cordova, pushwoosh

Is possible to send pushes from backend (using Pushwoosh remote API) to any device thats be inside a defined geozone? Can I use for do that the getNearestZone function? I don't understand it at all, I figured out that the getNearestZone function let me know the distance to the nearest geozone configurated by the pushwoosh panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoZones by default are intended to work automatically. When users enter a GeoZones, they receive push message triggered by it.

Currently, the manual/scheduled push messages can be delivered via Tags only, i.e. to Cities and Countries.

There is an Enterprise method, that lets you get recent coordinates of all devices (!) with their IDs via API. In this case you can target these devices via their IDs directly, or put a Tag on them. You can also dynamically set a GeoZone in the area of your interest via API (also an Enterprise method), for example in the zone with high density of your subscribers.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean to "Enterprise method"?

Comment: The one that is available on "Enterprise account" only at the moment.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, you refers to an method of the Pushwoosh remote api?